# How can I keep my custom entry in /etc/hosts?

Tags: 11.10, hosts

Since I upgraded my laptop to Ubuntu 11.10 32-bit, the entry I add to /etc/hosts for my home server keeps disappearing on boot.  I have to edit the hosts file every time I start up and want to access my server (which is most times) and I’d really rather not.  Any idea what’s causing this?  Here’s my edited /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   galileo
192.168.3.10    myserver

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not normal but shows up for some systems. [Here is a bug from Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/659872). 
So, you can upgrade Network Manager using [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mathieu-tl/+archive/nm). But I don't know how good it is and even necassary.

You can simply use this after changing the file:

```
sudo chattr +i /etc/hosts
```

So, it will be closed for any changes. If you want to change it in the future use this:

```
sudo chattr -i /etc/hosts
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing. This is a bit like killing a mosquito with a sledgehammer, so if there's another way, you should do so. But, this *will* work.

Comment: chattr worked — thanks for the solution and the bug link

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad that it worked.