# /etc/hosts file not being used before DNS server query

Tags: dns, hosts

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 and I have made entries in `/etc/hosts`, but instead of looking into the `hosts` file, queries to my configured DNS server are being made first.

How can I make Ubuntu query the `/etc/hosts` file first?

Thanks.

Comment: Is [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/84517/how-can-i-keep-my-custom-entry-in-etc-hosts?rq=1) helps ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion NikTh but that's not my problem. My entires aren't being removed, they are always there, they just aren't being used. If I execute `host www.somesite.com` where "www.somesite.com" is an entry in my hosts file, I seem to always get the IP given out by my DNS server which is different to that in my hosts file. Sometimes it works, mostly it doesn't though.

Comment: Did you check if `files` is listed BEFORE `dns` under `hosts` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`? This is the definition of the order in which they will be queried.

Comment: Good suggestion; `cat nsswitch.conf | grep hosts`   
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out I am a massive buffoon;

The `host` command just seems to ignore the /etc/hosts file and perform queries against your configured DNS servers directly. If I `ping www.somesite.com` I am using my /etc/hosts file entry, and after installing wireshark I can see that chrome is too.

Hope that helps someone!